# Optmizing scanned pages in a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, plugins, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm working on an automation project which requires me to recognize text in scanned pdfs(images).I need to write a code in python which converts the entire PDF(scanned) into readable PDF using recognize text function in Acrobat Pro DC.

I've written the following code in python so far:

```
avDoc = Dispatch("AcroExch.AVDoc")
pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
app = Dispatch("AcroExch.App")
app.MenuItemExecute("Cpt:CapturePages")
```

This opens up the pdf and takes me to the screen containing the 'recognize text' button. How can I click that button and have my desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to OCR a PDF so it is searchable?

Comment: No. I just want to convert the scanned pdf into readable pdf using python. Input : scanned pdf file. Output: readable pdf. PS: I am using adobe acrobat APIs.

Comment: @Prabal I think Rick was right. You are trying to OCR a PDF.

Comment: Yeah, I also think so. Any help about how to go ahead with this?

Comment: Yes Rick. Any idea?